# How to work with date command in a bash script through variable

Tags: bash, awk, date, timestamps

I have a file with specific dates and i want to convert them to UTC format. so I prepared a small script

I get below errors:

```
date: option requires an argument -- 'd'
Try `date --help' for more information.
date: extra operand `16:16:53'
```

Content of my File looks this:

```
20191014161653042nmd
20191014161653052egc
20191004081901490egc
20191004081901493nex
20191004081901497nex
20191004081902531nex
20191004081902534ksd
```

My code looks like this:

```
for i in $(cut -f1 Firstfile)
do
echo "$i" > tmpfile
TIME=$(awk '{print substr($1,1,14)}' tmpfile | sed -re 's/^([0-9]{8})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/\1\\ \2:\3:\4/' | xargs date +@%s -d | xargs date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" -d)
MSec=$(awk '{print substr($1,15,3)}' tmpfile)
Msg=$(awk '{print substr($1,18,3)}' tmpfile)
echo -e "$TIME.$MSec $Msg" >> ResultFile
done
```

When I use the command individually it works fine and I get the desired result.

```
awk '{print substr($1,1,14)}' tmpfile | sed -re 's/^([0-9]{8})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/\1\\ \2:\3:\4/' | xargs date +@%s -d | xargs date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" -d
```

What is the mistake I am doing in this with the script? why does it not work when I pass it through a script in for loop?

Expected Result:

```
2019-10-14T20:16:52.042 nmd
2019-10-14T20:16:52.052 egc
2019-10-04T12:19:01.490 egc
```

and so on

Comment: Do you have GNU awk (`gawk`)? if so you can probably simplify the conversion significantly using the builtin `mktime` and `strftime`

Comment: Your script works here, I can't reproduce the problem. But you could remove the loop and tmpfile and use `xargs -n1` to pass one argument after another to `date`. A more compact version would be `sed -re 's/^([0-9]{8})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).*/\1\\ \2:\3:\4/' Firstfile | xargs -n1 date +@%s -d | xargs -n1 date -u +"%FT%T" -d >> ResultFile`

Comment: I appreciate your response. How do I get the rest of the content? I want my output in this format
2019-10-14T20:16:52.042 nmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are passing too much data to `date` using `xargs`.  Also, you don't pass the extra text string at the end to make it part of the output.

It would be better to do the whole operation in an `awk` script.  Both GNU `awk` and `mawk` has functions for doing basic timestamp manipulations:

```awk
{
        YYYY    = substr($1, 1, 4)   # year
        mm      = substr($1, 5, 2)   # month
        dd      = substr($1, 7, 2)   # day
        HH      = substr($1, 9, 2)   # hour
        MM      = substr($1, 11, 2)  # minute
        SS      = substr($1, 13, 2)  # seconds
        sss     = substr($1, 15, 3)  # fractional seconds

        text    = substr($1, 18)     # the rest

        tm = mktime(sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s %s", YYYY, mm, dd, HH, MM, SS))
        printf("%s.%s %s\n", strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tm, 1), sss, text)
}
```

This picks out the various components of the input timestamp into various variables using `substr()`.  A Unix time is then calculated using `mktime()` (it's assumed that the input time is in the local time zone) and this is converted to a (UTC) timestamp string in the appropriate format using `strftime()`.

Note that the fractional seconds (`sss` in the code) are never part of the time computations and are instead just transferred as is from the input the output.

Running it:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
2019-10-14T14:16:53.042 nmd
2019-10-14T14:16:53.052 egc
2019-10-04T06:19:01.490 egc
2019-10-04T06:19:01.493 nex
2019-10-04T06:19:01.497 nex
2019-10-04T06:19:02.531 nex
2019-10-04T06:19:02.534 ksd
```

See the documentation for `mktime()` and `strftime()` in your `awk` manual.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version using sed and bash

```
 sed -re 's/^([0-9]{8})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(([0-9]{3,}){0,1})([a-z].*)$/D="\1\ \2:\3:\4";M="\5";E="\7"/' /tmp/tmpfile  |\ 
  xargs -d'\n' -I=:= bash -c  '(=:=;echo $(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.$M" -d "TZ=\"America/New_York\" $D" )  $E)'
```

i did only 1 sed step to avoid `awk + sed`
i removed all `\` in the second part of sed

i use `-I` option of xargs to specify where i will use my arg , like `{}` in `find`

to avoid to use twice date , i use the `TZ` option in `-d` option of date

Here i use `America/New_York` as a timezone for the input , you must change to the right value .

Comment: I am trying to get this format. your version is excluding the characters other than time. How to get in this format? I appreciate your response. 
2019-10-14T20:16:52.042 nmd